# Как отследить выполнение js скрипта?

Tags: javascript

В div скрипт добавляет класс. Нужно сделать так,чтобы этот класс не добавлялся. Как это сделать? Как понять в каком именно скрипте, и где добавляется этот класс. Вопрос возможно глупый, но я фронтом в принципе не занимаюсь, поэтому прошу помощи

Comment: Поиск по проекту пробовали? Попробуйте поискать этот самый класс. Или второй вариант инспектнуть страницу(Ctrl+U) и попробовать поискать в js файлах этот самый класс

Comment: откройте панель разработчика в Chrome, проинспектируте элемент и в правом меню есть вкладка Event Listeners, поищите там ваш обработчик